# Summation of powers

Tags: summation

I have come across the following in my textbook:

$$\sum_{i=0}^{20} 5^i = \frac{5^{21}-1} {4} $$

There is no explanation of how this result was achieved. Could anyone help walk-through how this would be calculated?

Answer (score 1):

It is a general fact that, for any number $x\neq 1$, 
$$\sum_{i=0}^nx^i=\frac{x^{n+1}-1}{x-1}$$
(See [the Wikipedia page on geometric progressions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_progression).)

You can see this is true by expanding out the product
$$\begin{align*}
(x-1)\sum_{i=0}^nx^i&=(x-1)(x^n+x^{n-1}+\cdots+x+1)\\
&=\begin{split}
x^{n+1}+x^n+\cdots+x^2+x\\
\quad-x^n -x^{n-1}-\cdots-x-1
\end{split}\\\\
&=x^{n+1}-1
\end{align*}$$

Comment: I you read this equality from right to left, it's a high school  formula.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this: multiply your sum, whose value $S$ you want to find 
$$S=\sum_{i=0}^{20} 5^i = 1 + 5 + 5^2 + \cdots + 5^{20}$$
by $5$, so each term gets multiplied by $5$
$$ 5 + 5^2 + 5^2 + \cdots + 5^{21}$$
This equals of course $5S$. Notice that it differs a bit from $S$ : the first term $1$ gets dropped, but then a new term $5^{21}$ appears at the end. 
So this also must be $S - 1 + 5^{21}$. Oh, you did not get $S$ yet, but you surely have an equation for $S$:
$$5S = S-1 + 5^{21}$$
Think you can solve that?